# Firebase References undeclared

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a new Xcode project, added the 'Firebase' pod to my pod file and installed it, and added the Google-services.plist file and the rest according to the Firebase documentation.

*import Firebase* works fine, but if I try

```
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!
```

in the same ViewController, then it throws an error:

> Use of undeclared type 'FIRDatabaseReference'

And this happens for any Firebase References. Any ideas on this? I am very new to Swift and the xCode IDE.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just had the same problem, but after a while I realized that I was missing an entry in the pod-file, your pod-file should contain:

```
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

Hope it works now :)

Comment: Add the line to your Podfile and then just run "pod update" in your terminal

Comment: don't know why but for me it doesn't work https://take.ms/UtATN

Answer (score 12):

EDIT:
I found the real problem behind.
Firebase had update. User need to update the firebase version via cocopod.
After update the cocopod, can use everything normally same as firebase Doc.

==========================================

I have the same problem, but cannot fix it by updating the pod-file.

Finally, I find out a solution.

Google teach us to import only

> import Firebase

Just add:

> import FirebaseDatabase

and everything will become fine

Answer (score 2):

In your Podfile, add pod

```
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

Then import Firebase Database in your ViewController

```
import FirebaseDatabase
```

Create a globle `var ref` that you can use it anywhere in viewcontroller

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
```

Now, In `viewDidLoad` Define the `ref`

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

Answer (score 1):

As in swift4 the  `FIRDatabaseReference` has been renamed to `DatabaseReference`

So, use:

`var ref:DatabaseReference`

Answer (score 1):

On your Podfile, add additional line of

```
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

Then on your code section

```
import FirebaseDatabase
```

And it should work now, with the following code:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by removing `"FIR"` form the words `("FIRDatabaseReference" and "FIRDatabaseHandle")`

Also that import  "Firebase" in the viewController