# Firebase IOS on Swift: Use of undeclared type 'DatabaseReference'

Tags: ios, swift, database, xcode, firebase

I had update/re-install the Podfile, but no result.

Here is my full code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

var ref: DatabaseReference! //Use of undeclared type 'DatabaseReference'

class ScreenListChatViewController: UIViewController {

    //ref = Database.database().reference()

    @IBOutlet weak var btnMenu: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnMenu.toggleMenu(screen: self)
    }
}
```

my Podfile:

```
target 'AppChat' do
  use_frameworks!

    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase References undeclared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523375/firebase-references-undeclared)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try Shift + CMD + K to clean your project then CMD + B to rebuild

Comment: @chuthienphuoc if you just forgot to clean your project, then please delete your question; trivial cleanups are off-topic on Stack Overflow as the code from your question becomes irrelevant.